# Why does scanf ( in C) seem to react only after a second input?

Tags: c, scanf

Can someone please take a look and advise why the program does not move forward after the scanf gets a char(&), but waits for another char to be entered?

```
char user_char, hist_axis;
int axis_char_ok = 0,grade, max_count=0,j,k,m=1,grades[9] = {0};

printf(" Please enter a character:  \n");
scanf(" %c ", &user_char);
```

Comment: Why don't you use just `"%c"` in scanf?

Answer (score 2):

The space following `%c` will eat up as much white space as possible, so it won't stop until you enter something that *isn't* a space or a line break (or an end-of-file).

If you change `" %c "` to `" %c"` then the problem should go away.

Comment: Thank you so much! you made my week, not only my day!  This solved the problem.